# build cordova android app give error in ionic application

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to run this command `ionic cordova platform add android`

in open source ionic project and I am getting this error

```
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@6.0.2" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" for android

The Android Persistent storage location now defaults to "Internal". Please check this plugin's README to see if your application needs any changes in its config.xml.

If this is a new application no changes are required.

If this is an update to an existing application that did not specify an "AndroidPersistentFileLocation" you may need to add:

      "<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />"

to config.xml in order for the application to find previously stored files.
        
Installing "cordova-plugin-androidx" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 10.0.0, failed version requirement: <9.0.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-androidx' for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-badge" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-chooser" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

        After much discussion and analysis of the market, we have decided to discontinue support for Android 4.0 (ICS) in Crosswalk starting
with version 20.

        So the minSdkVersion of Cordova project is configured to 16 by default.
    
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview': CordovaError: Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
    at Context.requireCordovaModule (C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\Context.js:57:15)
    at module.exports (C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\plugins\cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview\hooks\after_plugin_install\000-shared_mode_special.js:6:28)
    at runScriptViaModuleLoader (C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:157:32)
    at runScript (C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:136:12)
    at C:\asu-mobile\moodleapp2\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:108:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd platform add android exited with exit code 1.
```

I am new in ionic and I searched a lot and changed cordova-android and check the config file but still can not solve this problem, can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is inside the cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview plugin. Have you tried building without that plugin? does that work?

If you really need the plugin. There is an open pull-request that solves this exact issue (https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/pull/254/commits), you could make those changes yourself and patch the plugin with patch package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package). The plugin is no longer maintained, so the PR is probably never going to be merged.

I kinda doubt that you really need the plugin though, since almost nobody else is using it. Are you sure you need it? Can you not do the same thing with cordova-plugin-inappbrowser (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html) and/or cordova-plugin-browsertab? (the latter is also quite deprecated, but we still use it)

Also, If you are using corodova-android 11 (or 10 for that matter), you do not need cordova-plugin-androidx, because it is included in cordova-anrdoid.

Comment: unfortunately, I can not remove it, it is an open-source application and all I need is to change some colors and build it, and I do not have much experience in ionic , I am using cordova-android 10.1.2

Comment: Then I am afraid you need to patch it (or find a fork with the changes already included), luckily, I think you can just copy that pr exactly. If you make those changes in the plugin folder inside node-modules. and run `npx patch-package <package-name>` (after installing path-package) It will create a patch file that is run automatically whenever the plugins are installed again.

Comment: 10.1.2 no longer needs androidX I believe: "In this release, we have completely migrated to the AndroidX library and no longer support the Android Support Library." from 10.0.0 release notes: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/07/20/cordova-android-10.0.0.html